# Grouped scatterplot over grouped barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a grouped barplot with scatterplots colored for individual data points overlaid on the bars (I'm aware of the advantages of boxplots, but they are not standard in my field).
As I am new to R, I am mostly working by cutting and pasting bits of code in a semi-logical trial and error process, and here is the closest I have been able to come. It using the sample dataset "Males".

```
p <- ggplot(Males, aes(factor=year, fill=year, y=wage, x=ethn))
p + stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "bar", position="dodge") +
    stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar", mult=1, 
       color="yellow", position="dodge") + 
    geom_jitter(aes(size=.05, col=industry),position=position_dodge(width = 0.8))

ymax not defined: adjusting position using y instead
```

[image]

Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation points to post an image of the output, but basically the dots are all the same color as the column they overlay, instead of having a mix of different industries (colors) over each column.

My understanding is that the ymax error I got has nothing to do with the problem I'm having. Anyway, I'd be glad of any suggestions people can offer.

Comment: If you post a link to an image (say, on imgur), someone with enough rep can edit it into your question. You should also share your data, or at least the top of your data with `dput(head(Males, 10))`.

Comment: but barplots have counts on the y and scatterplots have raw data. so you are going to have two separate y-axes, is that correct? hadley doesnt like those and thus it requires some work since you not only will have two aesthetic scales (labels) but also two data scales (counts and y-values)

Comment: OK, a pic of my output is here: http://imgur.com/rId911Z
The dataset that I am using to demonstrate my issue is here: http://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/Ecdat/Males.csv

I dont need to separate Y-axes because my only purpose to visualize the distribution of points from different industries in each year+ethnicity bar. So the y-axis should be exactly the same (wage), as should the splitting of the factor groups (by ethnicty and then by year within ethnicity). I am not interested in counts at all.

Comment: Also, a bit more detail about my actual purpose: I am trying to visualize data from an experiment called "pre-pulse inhibition of acoustic startle". In short, subjects from three different genotype groups (KO, WT, and HET) were each tested with three different levels of pre-pulse intensity. I want to show my measurements of startle inhibition at each level of prepulse (75, 80, 95 dB), grouped by genotype.
Unfortunately I could not find a standard sample dataset that exactly mirrors these conditions, so I picked the "males" one because it can be used similarly.

Comment: also, to be clear, the barplots are not counts either. Bars are means, scatterplots are raw data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having, I think, is that some geometries, such as `geom_point` and `geom_jitter` do not use or allow the `factor` aesthetic for grouping along the x-axis.

Thus when you plot other geoms on top of a chart where `factor` is *not* ignored, such as `geom_bar`, the `factor` setting is ignored for some layers but not for `bar`, and you don't get year-resolved columns of points.

To solve the problem, I would try using `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap` to indirectly get the x-axis groupings that you want.

For example:

```
require(Ecdat)
data(Males)
quartz(height=6, width=12)

ggplot(Males, aes(x=year, y=wage)) +
  facet_grid(.~ethn) +
  stat_summary(mapping=aes(fill=year), fun.y=mean, geom='bar') +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_sdl, geom='errorbar', color='yellow') +
  geom_jitter(aes(color=industry), 
              position=position_jitter(width=0.2), alpha=0.8)

quartz.save('SO_29610340.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Yes!! That worked like a charm! All I had to do was change the parameters for the error bars to what I wanted, so the final code was like this:


`require(Ecdat)
data(Males)
quartz(height=6, width=12)

ggplot(Males, aes(x=year, y=wage)) +
  facet_grid(.~ethn) +
  stat_summary(mapping=aes(fill=year), fun.y=mean, geom='bar') +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar", mult=1, 
       color="yellow") +
  geom_jitter(aes(color=industry), 
              position=position_jitter(width=0.2), alpha=0.8)`

Result: http://imgur.com/tDx9O2N

Mods can mark this question as answered.

Comment: I don't have enough points to upvote, so I guess my thanks will have to do :(